# zsh autocompletion for sudo-like command

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I have a tool that runs other tools, that I would like to enable completion from the commands it runs.  For example:

```
mytool git grep --<TAB>
```

Should autocomplete for git grep.  This works fine with e.g. `sudo`:

```
sudo git grep --<TAB>
```

Shows the autocompletions for `git grep`.

How do I achieve this with my own tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `_normal`, [just like `_sudo` does](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/f4a248f9d38dc02d65610395f4c7f9a95a5d6612/Completion/Unix/Command/_sudo#L59).

See also the [documentation for `_normal`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fnormal).